# Check if Graph is a Directed Graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

For the function below, I have tried to write a method to test if a matrix representation of a graph is a directed graph.  It should contain at least one edge but no corresponding edge.

```
//G- Graph
//N - Nodes
bool isDigraph(bool G[N][N]) {
for (int rows = 0; rows < N; rows++)
    for (int columns = 0; columns < N; columns++)
        if (rows != columns && G[rows][columns] == 1)
            return false; // returns false if is not a directed graph
return true; // return true if it is a directed graph
}
```

The goal here is to show the graph is directed. I want to make sure the function returns false if the graph is empty and it has a self-loop.

- Although I did not get errors, the problem is it always returns true when my graph is empty and when it has a self-loop.

- Is there something I should add to my code?  Is there a way to show that it contains at least one edge but not a corresponding edge?
  If there is something I should add to my question to make it clear, please let me know.

Comment: Did you mean `G[rows][columns]` in your `if`?

Comment: @StephenNewell yes I meant to use G[rows][columns]

Comment: @fabian  I did mention that my function returns true every time I use it when the graph is empty and has a self-loop

Answer (score 0):

To check if a graph is directed given an adjacency matrix you can look for any asymmetry about the main diagonal (that is, find an `i`, `j` pair where `G[i][j] != G[j][i]`) or find some true value along the main diagonal, which indicates a self-loop for some node.

```
bool is_digraph(int N, bool **G) {
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = row; col < N; col++) {
            if (row == col && G[row][col] || G[row][col] != G[col][row]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

So, a graph like

```
    0 1 2
  +------
0 | 0 0 0
1 | 0 0 0
2 | 0 0 1
```

is directed because we have a self-loop.

A graph like

```
    0 1 2
  +------
0 | 0 1 0
1 | 1 0 1
2 | 0 1 0
```

is undirected because we have no self-loops and symmetry about the diagonal. The graph looks like:

```
0 
|
1---2
```

Finally, a graph like

```
    0 1 2
  +------
0 | 0 0 0
1 | 1 0 1
2 | 0 1 0
```

is directed because we have an asymmetry:

```
0<----1<----2
      |     ^
      |     |
      +-----+
```